# How can I calculate the following values for my progress bar

Tags: reactjs

I have the following steps: ** 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 80000, 160000**
[image: My Status bar]

As you can see tiers not having the same difference between them.

this is my componentDidMount function

```
 async componentDidMount() {
// const { points } = this.props;
let points = 5000; // static points for testing;

// bronze tier
if (points <= 10000) {
  //points left to reach next level
  let pointsToNextLevel = 10000 - points;
  let earnedPointBar = points / 320;
  this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 0,
    currentTier: "Bronze",
    upComingTier: "Bronze",
    bar: earnedPointBar,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });

  if (points ==10000) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = 15000 - points;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 1,
      upComingTier: "Silver",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 15.4
    });
  }
}
// Silver tier
else if (points <= 15000) {
  let pointsToNextLevel = 15000 - points;
  let earnedPointBar = points / 305;
  this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 1,
    currentTier: "Silver",
    upComingTier: "Silver",
    bar: earnedPointBar,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });
  if (points == 15000) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = 20000 - points;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 2,
      upComingTier: "Gold",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 33.1
    });
  }
}
// Gold tier
else if (points <= 20000) {
  let pointsToNextLevel = 20000 - points;
  let earnedPointBar = points / 360;
  console.log("bar", earnedPointBar);
 this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 2,
    currentTier: "Gold",
    upComingTier: "Gold",
    bar: earnedPointBar,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });
  if (points == this.props.tiersData.goldpts) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.platinumpts - points;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 3,
      upComingTier: "Platinum",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 50.1
    });
  }
}
// Platinum tier
else if (points <= this.props.tiersData.platinumpts) {
  let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.platinumpts - points;
  this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 3,
    currentTier: "Platinum",
    upComingTier: "Platinum",
    bar: 50.1,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });
  if (points == this.props.tiersData.platinumpts) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.diamondpts - points;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 4,
      upComingTier: "Diamond",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 69.1
    });
  }
}
//  // Diamond tier
else if (points <= this.props.tiersData.diamondpts) {
  let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.diamondpts - points;
  this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 4,
    currentTier: "Diamond",
    upComingTier: "Diamond",
    bar: 69.1,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });
  if (points == this.props.tiersData.diamondpts) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.blackpts - points;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 5,
      upComingTier: "Black",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 86.1
    });
  }
}
//  // Black tier
else if (points <= this.props.tiersData.blackpts) {
  let pointsToNextLevel = this.props.tiersData.blackpts - points;
  this.setState({
    lastCompletedTier: 5,
    currentTier: "Black",
    upComingTier: "Black",
    bar: 86.1,
    pointsToNextLevel
  });
  if (points >= this.props.tiersData.blackpts) {
    //points left to reach next level
    let pointsToNextLevel = 0;
    this.setState({
      lastCompletedTier: 6,
      upComingTier: "Black",
      pointsToNextLevel,
      bar: 100
    });
  }
} else {
  let pointsToNextLevel = 0;
  this.setState({
    complete: true,
    lastCompletedTier: 6,
    upComingTier: "Black",
    pointsToNextLevel,
    bar: 100
  });
}
```

}

variable `Points` are points which user collected stored in database Every tier points store in database too like : `this.props.tiersData.bronzepts`, `this.props.tiersData.silverpts`.

> please consider the first three cases I have did not work on other ones. I mean for bronze tier, silver tier and gold tier only.

**I wanted exact bar size in %tage like if I have 5000 points and which is less than 10000 how much bar %tage will be?**

In conclusion, I need a proper percentage of the bar with respect to `points`.

Comment: You can transform width of bar and points into percentage, and then compare these value proportionally.

Also you can check source code of react bootstrap progress bar f.e.

Comment: I have to do with manual computations. can you explain that more?

Comment: And I have mentioned there is not a same position or difference in tiers

Comment: Yes percent is good idea. You can make the bar by 1000 points and then do 5000/160000 = 0.03125 => 0.03125*1000 = 31.25 so the bar will be on 31.25 points. And you use a lot of `if` function.. that does not look good.

Comment: @Omer but in this case bar should be at 7.5% but it going to 31.25% can you please check again?

Comment: Oh, you want to adjust the bar to numbers, okay, where's the 5000?

Comment: bronze at 15.4 silver at 33.1 gold at 50.1 platinum at 69.1 diamond at 86.1 black at 100

Answer (score 0):

### A difference in the ratio of the difference at each step level

Everything is 35000

The stairs are

0-20: 1: 1

20-40: 1: 4

40-80: 1: 8

80-160: 1:16

You should then divide the difference together by the 35000 bar.

Up to 20000 bar in normal ratio, for example you have **7000** then 7000/35000 = **20%**

++++++++++

And if you have **25000** then you do 25000-20000, 20000 you do nothing because they are in normal ratio

and 5000 you divide in ratio which is 1: 4 and then you get 21250/35000 = **60.7%**

+++++++++++

If your number is between 40 and 80, do the same.

If it's **60000** you do 60000-20000 = 40000 in 20000 you don't touch.

Then lower another 20000 and divide them by 4 then divide the remainder by 8.

40000-20000 = 20000 which is basically 20000/4 = 5000

And you have another 20000 left that you divide by 8 which is 2500

Then 20000 + 5000 + 2500 = 27500

27500/35000 = **78.57%**. And that's the 60000 percent on the bar.

What do you think?

Comment: tell me what do you think, i want to help :)

Comment: actually the tiers are not at the same difference I have devided the step bar according to me I have to devide the points into percentage as I did for the bar